# Edit MongoMapper Document

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

Nowhere in the MongoMapper documentation can I find any methods for actually editing documents. I can't find anything elsewhere, either. The only way I could find, is this method:

```
class User
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :name, String
end

user = User.create( :name => "Hello" )
user.name = "Hello?"

puts user.name # => Hello?
```

Is there an easier way to do this? I know that in DataMapper, I can edit multiple keys (or properties, in DM's case) at once, but with MM, I can only do one at a time.

Am I missing something, or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You edit your documents/objects the same way you'd edit an ActiveRecord object: assign some values to attributes and then call `save`.

Your example only has one key so here's one with multiple keys:

```
class User
    include MongoMapper::Document
    key :name, String
    key :email, String
    key :birthday, Date
    timestamps! # The usual ActiveRecord style timestamps
end
```

And then:

```
user = User.create(
    :name     => 'Bob',
    :email    => 'bob@example.com',
    :birthday => Date.today
)
user.save
```

And later:

```
user.name     = 'J.R.'
user.email    = 'dobbs@example.com'
user.birthday = Date.parse('1954-06-02')
user.save
```

Or there's `update_attributes`:

```
user.update_attributes(
    :name  => 'J.R. "Bob" Dobbs',
    :email => 'slack@example.com'
)
user.save
```

Maybe I'm not sure what you're asking.